# CLR System.NullReferenceException when forcing 'Set Next Statement' into 'if' block

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda, clr

### Background

I accept this isn't something that can occur during normal code execution but I discovered it while debugging and thought it interesting to share.

I think this is caused by the JIT compiler, but would welcome any further thoughts.

I have replicated this issue targeting the 4.5 and 4.5.1 framework using VS2013:

[image: VS2013 Premium 12.0.31101.00 Update 4. NET 4.5.50938]

---

### Setup

To see this exception `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` must be enabled:
`DEBUG` > `Exceptions...`

[image: Common Language Runtime Exceptions enabled]

I have distilled the cause of the issue to the following example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myEnum = MyEnum.Good;

            var list = new List<MyData>
            {
                new MyData{ Id = 1, Code = "1"},
                new MyData{ Id = 2, Code = "2"},
                new MyData{ Id = 3, Code = "3"}
            };

            // Evaluates to false
            if (myEnum == MyEnum.Bad) // BREAK POINT 
            {
                /*
                 * A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication6.exe

                   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                 */
                var x = new MyClass();

                MyData result;
                //// With this line the 'System.NullReferenceException' gets thrown in the line above:
                result = list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Code == x.Code);

                //// But with this line, with 'x' not referenced, the code above runs ok:
                //result = list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Code == "x.Code");
            }
        }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Good,
        Bad
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### To Replicate

Place a breakpoint on `if (myEnum == MyEnum.Bad)` and run the code. 
When the break point is hit, `Set Next Statement`(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) to be the opening brace of the `if` statement and run until:

[image: NullReferenceException thrown]

Next, comment *out* the first lamda statement and comment *in* the second - so the `MyClass` instance isn't used. 
Rerun the process (hitting the break, forcing into the `if` statement and running). You'll see the code works correctly:

[image: MyClass instantiated correctly]

Finally, comment *in* the first lamda statement and comment *out* the second - so the `MyClass` instance **is** used. Then refactor the contents of the `if` statement into a new method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myEnum = MyEnum.Good;

            var list = new List<MyData>
            {
                new MyData{ Id = 1, Code = "1"},
                new MyData{ Id = 2, Code = "2"},
                new MyData{ Id = 3, Code = "3"}
            };

            // Evaluates to false
            if (myEnum == MyEnum.Bad) // BREAK POINT 
            {
                MyMethod(list);
            }
        }

        private static void MyMethod(List<MyData> list)
        {
            // When the code is in this method, it works fine
            var x = new MyClass();

            MyData result;

            result = list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Code == x.Code);
        }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Good,
        Bad
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rerun the test and everything works correctly:

[image: MyClass instantiated correctly inside MyMethod]

---

### Conclusion?

My assumption is the JIT compiler has optimized out the lamda to always be null, and some further optimized code is running prior to the instance being initialized.

As I previously mentioned this could never happen in production code, but I would be interested to know what was happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a pretty inevitable mishap, not related to optimization.  By using the Set Next Statement command, you are bypassing *more* code than you can easily see from the source code.  It only becomes obvious when you look at the generated machine code.  Use Debug + Windows + Disassembly at the breakpoint.  You'll see:

```
            // Evaluates to false
            if (myEnum == MyEnum.Bad) // BREAK POINT 
0000016c  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],1 
00000170  setne       al 
00000173  movzx       eax,al 
00000176  mov         dword ptr [ebp-5Ch],eax 
00000179  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-5Ch],0 
0000017d  jne         00000209 
00000183  mov         ecx,2B02C6Ch               // <== You are bypassing this
00000188  call        FFD6FAE0 
0000018d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-7Ch],eax 
00000190  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-7Ch] 
00000193  call        FFF0A190 
00000198  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-7Ch] 
0000019b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax 
            {
0000019e  nop 
                /*
                 * A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication6.exe

                   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                 */
                var x = new MyClass();
0000019f  mov         ecx,2B02D04h             // And skipped to this
000001a4  call        FFD6FAE0 
// etc...
```

So, what is that mysterious code?  It isn't anything you wrote in your program explicitly.  You can find out by using the Set Next Statement command in the Disassembly window.  Move it to address `00000183`, the first executable code after the if() statement.  Start stepping, you'll see it executing the constructor of a class named `ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass5`

Otherwise well covered in existing SO questions, this is an auto-generated class for the lambda expression in your source code.  It is required to store captured variables, `list` in your program.  Since you skipped its creation, dereferencing `list` in the lambda is always going to bomb with NRE.

A standard case of a "leaky abstraction", C# has some of it but not outrageously so.  Nothing much you can do about it of course, you can certainly blame the debugger for not guessing at this correctly but it is a very difficult problem to solve.  It cannot easily find out if that code belongs to the if() statement or the code that follows it.  A design issue, debug info is line number based and there is no line of code.  Also in general a problem with the x64 jitter, it fumbles even in simple cases.  Which should be fixed in VS2015.

This is something you have to learn the Hard Way™.  If it is really, really important then I showed you how to set the next statement properly, you have to do it in the Disassembly view to make it work.  Feel free to report this issue at connect.microsoft.com, I'd be surprised if they didn't already know about it however.

Comment: Thanks. I'd looked through the IL but couldn't make any sense of it. The Disassembly window isn't something I knew about so that is very helpful.