# .Net to native variable declaration in if statement

Tags: .net, variables, memory-management, native-code

I stepped into a surprising issue trying to access memory in changing the normal path of my process.

I can't reproduce the issue in smaller code, but here is  the context :
 - Having numerous threads
 - Having an if statement
 - In the if "then" block Declaring and inializing a variable of a non native type (ex : System.DateTime)
Then in debug :
 - Do not meet the if condition, move the debugging cursor from the statement after the if to the first statement of the "then" block.
 - While initializing the inner variable, the programm crashes (nullrefexception).

This doesn't occurs if the variable is declared outside of the if or if the process enters the "then"clock normaly.

My opinion is that even if the memory of the variable is allocated outside of the if (in the scope of the function) the thread hasn't the right to access the memory until the process enters the if scope.
This would mean that the native compiler grants the thread ownership at the effective variable declaration.

Also the debugger's watch meet no problem in accessing this memory and get no exception.

I have no proof of that and would like to know any way to ensure (like seeing thread memory ownership).
And if it's true, isn't it an issue for the vs debugger that doesn't bind correctly IL and .Net in that case ?

Comment: You need to provide sample code as what you have said makes no sense.

Comment: As a note threads in .Net do not own memory.

Comment: The debugger's SetNext command is pretty dangerous, too easy to bypass code.  Random example [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28900002/17034).