# Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio moving debugger instruction pointer

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to move instruction pointer in XS or VS (backward)? I could not make it work so it seems to be not implemented or not possible to implement because of different effective code in IDE (C#) and native on simulator/device (obj-c, java).

There is resolved ticket for XS but it not seems to work.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2854

Comment: Do you want to use the "set the next statement" to skip code? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9(v=vs.100).aspx, a related case asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919855/dragging-the-instruction-pointer-backward-while-debugging-in-visual-studio

Comment: For example I want to drag the instruction pointer backward.