# Can I step back to previous breakpoint while debugging in Android Studio? (Drop the frames)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea

I would like to be able to execute previous breakpoint that I've just stepped over

I know Android Studio is based on Intellij Idea where it's possible [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867491/how-to-step-one-step-back-in-intellij).
Similar question asking the same but its related to Eclipse IDE [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611019/cannot-drop-to-frame)

There is also one answer that say's it's impossible.
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618959/how-to-step-back-a-line-of-code-with-android-studio-debugger)

I can see "Drop Frame" button. But it's disabled by default.
[image]

So is there any way to enable this button?

Comment: I suppose you have been using Visual Studio. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer you are referring to regarding **Eclipse** is still valid for **Android Studio**:

You **cannot** step back to previous breakpoint in **Android Studio** because **DalvikVM** and **Android Runtime (ART)** do not support it.

You can enable the "Drop Frame" button if you debug JUnit tests as they run on a standard virtual machine (although I'm guessing this is not what you are after).

It is probably the only reason why the button exists.

[Google's User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) ignores it completely.

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly new to Android Studio, so I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but have you tried playing around with the Frames window?

[image]

It allows you to backtrack the app's process, even reaching old breakpoints.

Comment: I see I can go through method calls but where can I go back to previous breakpoint?

Comment: This is unfortunately as far as my experience goes with the tool, maybe someone else knows more.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot step backwards to a previous breakpoint that you have already chosen to continue past. You would have to create a saved state of your program at every break point to be able to do this, which would consume more memory than is worth designing the debugger with. You could although emulate this sort of functionality by forking your program everywhere you want to put a breakpoint.

-edit: This would be more feasible in eclipse than in android studio, as you would have to start another virtual device for android. say goodbye to your memory :p

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 (Q) has supported this feature. It works well on my Pixel 2.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Please see below image

> Using red down arrow to step in and blue up arrow using to step out.

:

[image]

Comment: okay Thanks  :)   Please see this 
 answer , its working fine for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46524922/6720935

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question!

Answer (score -4):

> Use **ALT + F9** for next break point.
>
> For me (macOs Sierra) it's Previous step **cmd + alt + R**

Comment: The question is about the **previous** breakpoint, not the next one!

Comment: Did you try it? I use AS 2.3.3 on windows and it does not work. ctrl+alt+r does nothing. The *drop frame* menu item is disabled.